# Assigning values to variables in a Dynamic manner

Tags: sql-server

The following code assigns values dynamically to the variables Column1 to Column5

```
DECLARE @Column1     INT=0,
    @Column2     INT=0,
    @Column3     INT=0,
    @Column4     INT=0,
    @Column5     INT=0,
    @I           INT=0,
    @STMT_ASSIGN NVARCHAR(100)

SET @I = 1

WHILE ( @I <= 5 )
BEGIN
  SET @STMT_ASSIGN='SET @Column' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @I) + '='
                   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @I)

  IF @I = 1
    EXEC Sp_executesql
      @STMT_ASSIGN,
      N'@Column1 INT output',
      @Column1 = @Column1 output
  ELSE IF @I = 2
    EXEC Sp_executesql
      @STMT_ASSIGN,
      N'@Column2 INT output',
      @Column2 = @Column2 output
  ELSE IF @I = 3
    EXEC Sp_executesql
      @STMT_ASSIGN,
      N'@Column3 INT output',
      @Column3 = @Column3 output
  ELSE IF @I = 4
    EXEC Sp_executesql
      @STMT_ASSIGN,
      N'@Column4 INT output',
      @Column4 = @Column4 output
  ELSE
    EXEC Sp_executesql
      @STMT_ASSIGN,
      N'@Column5 INT output',
      @Column5 = @Column5 output

  SET @I=@I + 1
END
```

Please suggest an idea to remove the if..else if.. part in order to make it as single `sp_execute` sql to assign values. Since I have to assign 50 values to 50 variables using one `EXEC sp_executesql` instead of writing 50 If..Else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
DECLARE @Column1     INT=0,
    @Column2     INT=0,
    @Column3     INT=0,
    @Column4     INT=0,
    @Column5     INT=0,
    @I           INT=0,
    @STMT_ASSIGN NVARCHAR(100),
    @command NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @I = 1

WHILE ( @I <= 5 )
BEGIN
  SET @STMT_ASSIGN='SET @Column' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @I) + '='
                   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @I)

    SET @command = 'EXEC Sp_executesql
          @STMT_ASSIGN,
          N''@Column'+CAST(I AS NVARCHAR(1))+' INT output'',
          @Column'+CAST(I AS NVARCHAR(1))+' = @Column'+CAST(I AS NVARCHAR(1))+' output'

    EXEC(@command)

  SET @I=@I + 1
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the Update. I have tried this query but I got the below error. [I am new to SQL server]. Actually I have already declared that variable. Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@STMT_ASSIGN".

Comment: That's because that variable is out of scope in your dynamic sql. What are you trying to do here? I don't see a complete sql statement anywhere in here or in your original post. And from what I have seen here I don't understand the need for a loop at all.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for your kind responses